# Suppressing a mayNotRespond Warning in iPhone App

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios4, suppress-warnings

I have an App with a Tab Controller, which has obviously a certain number of tabs. Every ViewController in the TabController, share some informations, so I decided to move those in the AppDelegate and to synthesize everything in a NSDictionary so I can access to those using

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedInformations];
```

The solution works fine and I guess it's pretty good (I accept better solutions). Obviously, the compiler warns me about the fact that [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] may not respond to the method sharedInformations because he didn't found the method in the protocols, but I know it will.

The question is: how do I suppress that warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast it:

```
[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] sharedInformations];
```

or slightly tidier:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
… = appDelegate.sharedInformation;
```

You could also encapsulate your shared info in a Singleton class and do something like

```
#import "MySharedInfo.h"

MySharedInfo *sharedInfo = [MySharedInfo sharedInfo];
// etc.
```